# rails - how to restore postgres database from dev to production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

I've used the following command to create backup and restore my postgres database from dev to production but after that I'm unable to create new Record

```
Create a database backup:

PGPASSWORD=$DB_PASSWORD pg_dump \
    --host=$DB_HOST \
    --username=$DB_USERNAME \
    --dbname=$DB_NAME \
    --format=custom \
    --file=D:/output.dmp

Restore a database from a backup

PGPASSWORD=$DB_PASSWORD pg_restore  \
    --host=$DB_HOST \
    --username=$DB_USERNAME \
    --dbname=$DB_NAME \
    D:/output.dmp
```

```
DB Setting:

default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 10 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: dev_db
  username: postgres
  password: mypass

production:
  <<: *default
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

DATABASE_URL: postgres://username:password@production_host.com/db_name

PS: Database_name, username in production and dev are different.

Error: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "table_name_pkey"
Detail: Key (id)=(1) already exists.

what i can understand from this error is "after restoring, when i create a new record and save to db then this error occurred...So basically, the after restoring primary key of table is not incrementing according to data for ex: if a restore a table with 80 records with pkey 1-80 then after when i create a new record and try to save it to the table it's pkey start with 1 (instead of 81) which is already present in the table after restoring"

Comment: Sounds like the restore is working fine, it is the thing after that which is getting an error.  But you didn't show us what that thing is.

Comment: I Edit the question about my problem

Comment: pg_restore sets up sequences correctly for me.  We still don't know what you are doing, as "saving a record" is pretty vague.  Maybe your rails model is broken somehow.  At least tell us what the SQL command is which throws the error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to restore the dump into an empty database, otherwise these errors will likely occur. Either manually drop and re-create the database before you restore, or use `pg_dump --clean --create` to do it for you.